# App with own soft keyboard by default

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-input-method

I'm creating a app and want him to have his own custom soft keyboard by default, but I don't know how do this.

So far I have the app and a separate app for the keyboard, I tried to set the custom keyboard by default but don't managed to do that, the only way I found for enable him is via shell and enabling manually in the phone configuration, the shell command that I use:

```
ime enable package/appName
ime set package/appName
```

I tried to execute this commands via:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
```

Tried to put in the init files too, tried to substitute the default android keyboard, but nothing works.

If anyone can help me you have my thanks.

Comment: "I'm creating a app and want him to have his own custom soft keyboard by default, but I don't know how do this" -- that is not possible. Malware authors would *love* the ability to force users to use their input method editors. "Tried to put in the init files too" -- are you trying to build a custom ROM? If yes, clearly there is some way to replace the default keyboard, as many device manufacturers do that.

Comment: Yeah, I have a custom ROM.

Comment: I doubt that any of the techniques you outlined in your question are how device manufacturers replace the default keyboard. On the whole, Stack Overflow is not a great resource for custom ROM developers, though, so I don't know how much help you will get here, particularly since your question title implies an app, not a custom ROM.